# WPF , Clicking on TextBox should check the RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, radio-button

I have a `RadioButton` and a `TextBox` inside one `StackPanel` as shown below:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbSelectedQuantity" GroupName="CardQuantity"
          FontSize="14" Margin="5"
          Content="Selected Quantity">
        </RadioButton>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtSelectedQuantity" Width="50" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right"
        Text="0"></TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
```

Here is My Scenario: If I click inside the TextBox, my Radio Button should be checked automatically.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the `GotFocus` Event for the TextBox and set the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` property to `True`

```
private void txtSelectedQuantity_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rbSelectedQuantity.IsChecked = True;
    }
```